# Validate html code with node.js

Tags: html, node.js, validation, w3c-validation

I want to validate some HTML documents in a node.js application. I already found some node.js modules like w3cjs and w3c-validate, but it seems that they are only working online. Because I have to check many small HTML documents, I'm searching for a solution that works offline, without internet.

Do you know how to integrate the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html) in a node application? Or what are other ways to check HTML syntax? Maybe something like a DOM parser?

Comment: Have you tried - https://github.com/mozilla/html5-lint ?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. No I haven't tried yet. On the first look at html5-lint I found "Python front-end to the Mozilla Labs' HTML Validator Web Service". So it does not seem to work offline, right? Regards

Comment: No ..on the github page...there is **node.js** usage...

Comment: I just implemented a short example with the html5-lint module in nodejs. Yes it works but it needs internet for working. I am searching for a solution that works without internet. Thank you!

Comment: The validator schema is in internet...so it is using that. If we find something with using net..i will update..

Comment: [PhantomJS as an HTML Validator](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/04/06/phandom.html)

Comment: Take a look at [htmllint](http://htmllint.github.io/)